# Single password authorization in Mojolicious

Tags: perl, basic-authentication, mojolicious

I want to implement single password authorization instead of Basic-Auth in Mojolicious.

I need the standard basic-auth field to be displayed, but to only ask the user for a password, without having to see the username field.

```
plugin 'basic_auth', { realm => '', authenticator => sub {
    my ($password) = @_;

    return $password eq 'correct_password';
}};


my $authenticated = $c->basic_auth(realm => 'Restricted area', username => '', password => 'password');
    unless ($authenticated) {
        return { error => 'Authentication failed' };
    }
```

Basic authentication is very easy to implement, but I did not find the ability to request only a password.

Maybe someone knows how to request only an access password?

I tried basic auth, but  there is no possibility to exclude login field.

[image]

Comment: Basic auth is based on a specification forcing ID / password pairs. If you want only the password, you can't use basic auth, and therefore need to use a different Mojolicious plugin, or write your own. Maybe [this doc could help](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Adding-a-plugin-to-your-application), as I don't think a Mojolicious single password plugin is available on CPAN).

Comment: Also, the browser part: if I understand your needs correctly, what you want to achieve is sending a temporary single use password through email. You might have to set up your own HTML page for that, as this default pop up window (screenshot) is something implemented in the core of the browser. I am not sure how it can be manipulated through JavaScript, but doesn't look like the way to go to me.

Comment: Basic auth is handled by the browser, so you can't change the dialog box presented to the user. But I think when I last did this, you can leave at least the password, and possibly username, blank?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, in fact, js has the ability to display a password field through the standard browser password entry window, using JS:
var password = prompt("Please enter your password:");

I just didn’t want to complicate this and was looking for a ready-made solution for mojolicious.

Comment: The idea is to generate temporary passwords through another mojo application, the passwords will be saved in a local json file.
I just want to ask user to enter a single password, then check a password, if is exist and not expired, using perl.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use HTML's `<dialog>` element? Widely adopted since 2022. Easy to make with only a greeting, password field, and Log In and Cancel buttons. With an inner form it can send the password to your Mojo - or any other - script the usual way. And you can style the dialog as needed. If you want a minimal example, I'll post one. Ref: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)